# Forwarding and Storing Request Stream in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, stream

I have a service, written using ASP.NET Web API 2. Part of it involves receiving images and forwarding them onto a different web service (on a different machine). So, the flow is:

- Client does an HTTP POST to my service, with the binary image as the body.
- In my controller, I call Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().
- That Stream is ultimately asyncronously sent as the body of an HTTP request.

With this design, I believe that bytes are forwarded to the other service as they are received, so we do not need to wait for the entire image to be read before sending them on.

That's fine, but now I want to store a copy of the image, for later analysis.

- I can't just Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) since the stream is closed after being read the first time.
- I could use ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), wrap this in a MemoryStream, and then easily send this to both the remote service, and to Azure blob storage. But this would slow down the service, as the entire image needs to be read before sending it on.

Is there an alternative approach which I haven't considered? Is my underlying assumption about passing on the request stream to another request valid?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a pointer from a colleague, I eventually found this sample which shows how to wrap the HttpContent with something that writes both to the original stream, and a file: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ResponseEntityProcessorSample/Handlers/HttpContentProcessor.cs

And this sample which shows how to relay a request asyncronously: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RelaySample/Controllers/RelayController.cs

Comment: both links are dead. this is the reason link only answers are discouraged on SO.

Comment: This might be what the 2nd link pointed at, but I'm not 100% sure. The path & file names are almost identical: https://github.com/aspnet/samples/blob/main/samples/aspnet/WebApi/RelaySample/Controllers/RelayController.cs